# Transforming a vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> to vector<A>

Tags: c++, vector, std, unique-ptr

There is a vector of `std::unique_ptr<A>`. I need to pass that data to a function that expects a vector of `A`.

I tried using `std::transform`, like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> a;

std::vector<A> aDirect;
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(),
    std::back_inserter(aDirect),
    [](std::unique_ptr<A> element)-> A { return *element; });
```

but it seems that `std::transform` tries to copy elements of `a` at some point, so that doesn't work, it fails as trying to reference a deleted function.

Of course, I could just do it manually with a for loop, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: Try `aDirect.reserve(a.size());` before calling `std::tranform`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change the lambda to take a const &

```
[](std::unique_ptr<A> const &element)-> A { return *element; });
```

to avoid copies due to resizing reserve correct size before transforming.

```
std::vector<A> aDirect;
aDirect.reserve(a.size());
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(),
               std::back_inserter(aDirect),
               [](std::unique_ptr<A> element) {
                   return *element;
               });
```

Comment: How would this help eliminate all the copies that occur when `std::vector` repeatedly reallocates itself, during the entire insertion operation?

Comment: I've tried the for approach and have gotten this:
`for (const std::unique_ptr<A>& element: a) { aDirect.push_back(*a); }`
which is both more compact and more readable. The solution you gave does fix the original issue though.